# Why there is no space between CardViews on Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I try to use the `CardView` and it works well below 5.0, but looks strange on Lollipop.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="card1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="card2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I meet the same question when i use the `RecyclerView`, should I have to add something if it runs on Lollipop?

Comment: add `LinearLayout` between the cards

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Set this on a `CardView`:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

From documentation:

> Add padding in API v21+ as well to have the same measurements with
>   previous versions.

Comment: I used the "app" namespace instead. Is "card_view" still used?

Comment: @wsgeorge that was from Android documentation, but I've edited it to more friendly app namespace.

Comment: looks better but how remove divider line?

Comment: @nonews You can try `android:divider="@null"`.

Answer (score 29):

Use this two tags below inside of your cardview:

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Answer (score 13):

first image is the expected behavior of card view. when the card has elevation the shadow falls on the bottom layers. In the pre-lollipop devices the elevation is made by adding padding. so the pre-lollipop devices will have a padding around the card view.

> Before L, CardView adds padding to its content and draws shadows to
>   that area. This padding amount is equal to maxCardElevation + (1 -
>   cos45) * cornerRadius on the sides and maxCardElevation * 1.5 + (1 -
>   cos45) * cornerRadius on top and bottom.

Comment: so the size of cardview we see in editor is not the real size we can use when below lollipop ,there is a part of it which is used to add the padding, and on lollipop the size in layout is the same as the real, it seems that give a padding of it looks better，but how should i do to separate them?

Comment: what you seen in the editor is what you get in real.
To have the same margin between the cards in all screens.set margin if the API lever is 21 or higher

Comment: This answer is correct. In addition to that, if you want to make the UI consistent w/o adding separate margins for values-21, you can set compat padding to true so that it will add the same padding in L as well.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding

Comment: @billgates after adding a margin the cardview looks good on both lollpop and pre-lollpop,thanks for your answer!

Comment: is it possible to remove the padding on pre-lollipop devices?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to your `Cardview`. But just adding that may give you an error. To avoid that error, you also have to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your `CardView`.

For example,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    // Other views here

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Some would add `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` and `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of those mentioned above. Both ways are correct.

If you want to know more about *app* in XML(Android), please go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692768/2818583) :

Although previous answers will solve the problem, they didn't explain what each attribute does. So to be more helpful to answer seekers,

`cardPreventCornerOverlap` attribute adds padding to CardView on v20 and before to prevent intersections between the Card content and rounded corners.

`cardUseCompatPadding` attribute adds padding in API v21+ as well to have the same measurements with previous versions.