# Error 'No resource identifier found' with Android sample project

Tags: android

I am trying to open the Android sample project - Navigation Drawer in Android Studio, but got error while building it.

These are the steps to reproduce it:

1. From Android Studio welcome page, select **Import an Android code sample**
2. Search for **Navigation Drawer**, select it and click 'Next'
3. Specify project location and click 'Finish'

> Error:(43) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutManager'
>   in package 'com.example.android.navigationdrawer'

Android Studio version is - 1.4 Beta 4

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The compiler cannot find this attribute in the `activity_navigation_drawer.xml`:

```
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
```

To fix this

1. Remove this attribute from the XML so your Recyclerview looks like this:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:layout_width="240dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="left|start"
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:divider="@null"/>
   ```
2. press the Gradle Sync button
3. In `NavigationDrawerActivity`, add the following 2 lines of code in your OnCreate();

   ```
   LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
   mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutmanager);
   ```

So your code now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutmanager);
    ....
```

Good luck

**Edit**: 
The reason why this the original xml code is no longer working, is most likely that the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace is no longer supporting the `layoutManager` attribute.

More info on the namespace can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692768/3708094

Comment: works but perhaps a little reasoning why the xml config doesnt work?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly still define LayoutManagers and more via xml. Here's an example using the native GridLayoutManager:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/posters_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:reverseLayout="false"
    app:spanCount="3"
    app:stackFromEnd="false" />
```

If you want to use a custom LayoutManager follow the rules defined here:

[R.attr.html#layoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/R.attr.html#layoutManager)

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the build.gradle file(module) to the newest version, I tried it and everything is OK now.

references:

> https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NavigationDrawer/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that gradle resolved all dependencies? I had the same problem when I occasionally removed recyclerview support library from dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```