# Android navigation drawer sample:Error:(43) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutManager'

Tags: android

I've started programming an app for android importing the Navigation Drawer code sample from android studio. Running it I got the error

```
Error:(43) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutManager' in package 'com.example.android.navigationdrawer'
```

I've followed the instructions found in [Error 'No resource identifier found' with Android sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607437/error-no-resource-identifier-found-with-android-sample-project) but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawer/com.example.android.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

I couldn't find another answer that I can adapt since my skills are quite basic.

The only differences from the original NavigationDrawer sample code are:

I removed from activity_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
```

I added the last two lines in this NavigationDrawerActivity snippet

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutmanager);
    ....
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what's exactly the question?

Comment: How do I fix the null object reference, or more in general how do I make the sample work?

Comment: @Iaaf The null object reference means that you attempted to set the layout of the `mDrawerList` before it has been _instantiated_ i.e. the `mDrawerList` does not exist and you're trying to set the `mLinearLayoutManager` on it. Basically, you probably added the 2 lines (LinearLayoutManager) above the `mDrawerList = (RecyclerView)...` contrary to what you have shown in the snippet.

Answer (score -1):

this Error means xml file dismiss or not define 
Create xml file or import