# What is the meaning of such lines like xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in android xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is XML property xmlns:app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493417/what-is-xml-property-xmlnsapp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to import **attributes** in `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to kind of import their libraries. which you can then access by their prefixs {android:,tools:,app:}
Example of of usage are

```
android:name="yourpackege.App"

tools:overrideLibrary="yourpackege.App"

app:showAsAction="never"
```

In the above examples **attributes** being

```
android:name, tools:overrideLibrary, app:showAsAction
```

Of course every single prefix has many more attributes for example

```
android:name,android:theme,android:value
```

Kindly note though that

> The app namespace is not specific to a library, but it is used for all attributes defined in your app [readhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace)

Just to test the explanation above if you remove lets say
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and rebuild your android application, you will get and error that looks something like [image]