# Android namespaces in XML files

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

1. If someone can explain what's the meaning of the namespaces(android , app , tool) in the XML files? is each word defines different library?
2. As I know ,in XML files the URI is just a string which gives a unique definition to the namespace , so how does the android app connect the namespace to the library?
3. Let say we gave the "android" word its default namespace , how come that in different elements we can choose different attributes? is each element(view item) has its unique attributes?

Comment: Look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)  it has a good enough explanation and for further go to the android documentations for the same . :)

Comment: did you check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

## app NameSpace

The `app` namespace is not specific to a library, but it is used for all attributes defined in your app, whether by your code or by libraries you import, effectively making a single global namespace for custom attributes - i.e., attributes not defined by the android system.

## android NameSpace

the `appcompat-v7` library uses custom attributes mirroring the `android:` namespace ones to support prior versions of android.

## tools NameSpace

The tools namespace is a specially recognized namespace by the Android tools, so all the attributes you define on view elements in the tools-namespace will be automatically stripped when the application is packaged and there is no runtime overhead.

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace) answer.

## In Short :

`android:text` --> what you would see while running the app.

`tools:text` --> what you would see just on preview window (when you need to design layout, but won't it to see on layout in app).

Comment: I believe OP already knew that. Also, I don't see how your "android NameSpace" section explained the `android` namespace. The "In Short" part is that is already known, and what needs explanation. First (copy-pasted) paragraph is useful though.