# NullPointerException when change Activity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, oncreateoptionsmenu

I changed my class from the Activity to AppCompatActivity.

And changed `item.getActionView()`  to  `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item)`

Now I get NPE in the following code.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuTxtSize);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int index = sp.getInt(getString(R.string.pr_text_size),
            Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.pr_default_text_size)));
    spinner.setSelection(index);


E/ACRA: ACRA caught a NullPointerException for com.alex.documentation java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setSelection(int)' on a null object reference at com.alex.message.activities.MessagesActivity
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Please include the stack trace and the actual line the NPE would be occuring on.

Comment: @Kiskae  I added stack trace in a question

Comment: @Rotwang Remove this as being marked as a duplicate. You referenced a simple question where someone is asking what an NPE is. This isn't a generic NPE question.

Comment: @JonTinsman All NPEs are the same old story... If you know what an NPE is, you also know how to remove it.

Comment: @Rotwang I don't know who put you on the high horse you are on, but not all NPE exceptions are the same. If the person writing the code is modifying an object they created then yes, it is a simple NPE; however, the OP had working code and then when they tried to convert to an AppCompatActivity, the code no longer worked and it is throwing an NPE.

As you can see from the accepted answer, it was not a simple "what is an NPE" but it had to do with the AndroidManifest.xml file needing to be modified.

Comment: @JonTinsman What is not clear in "Null Pointer Exception"? Of course it's a non instanced object which has been used. How is that different in what the accepted answer says?

Comment: @Rotwang SO post [marking duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) says `Remember: duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates. By the same token, many questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.` This question can't be answered by your link

Comment: @JonTinsman This question actually **can** be answered by my link. **If** you know what a NPE is, you also know how to handle it. But feel free to disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `app:actionViewClass`, not `android:actionViewClass` when using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Yes you are right. What's the difference between `app:****` and `android:******` ?

Comment: `android:` is system provided, while `app:` is provided by your app and the libraries it contains. See the [full explanation of the `android:` vs `app:` namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace/26692768#26692768) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was having issues when I merged two projects together (two team members started the same app in different repos). One was Activity while the other was AppCompatActivity that had the search action bar.