# Android - Run ADB push command with whitespace's

Tags: android, command-line, adb, android-debug, fastboot

I am trying to run an ADB command from HERE-Maps [Documentation page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-voice-instructions.html)  which says,

```
adb push voices /sdcard/Android/data/{YourAppNamespace}/files/voices-download
```

In above command the `"{YourAppNamespace}"` is the app name, In my case my app name is separated by a white space like `Google<space>Now` So if i am passing my application name with white space in between command is giving error because there's a white space in between.
How can I resolve it? Am I passing correct name? I copied my `app_name` from `res/strings.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "" quotes when white space is included in the command:

`adb push voices "/sdcard/Android/data/{YourAppNamespace}/files/voices-download"`

Comment: you just copied the same snippet from the documentation page. It doesn't answer my question , Question is, If my app name is `google now` so notice there's a space in between google and now, so how can i pass a command which I have space in between app name, Which is making command fail

Comment: i think in a answer changing is this  **" "** @GeekWithGlasses

Comment: @MohammadAli Sorry i think you interpreted that wrong, that double quoted is just for making focus on {YourAppNamespace} , i am simply passing my app name only, without any quotes symbol

Comment: okay okay i just see the change of the code so i just telling you @GeekWithGlasses

Comment: Putting my app_name inside double quotes made it possible , Cheers

Comment: Great! Thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with `app-name` and `app-namespace`

[AppNameSpace](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-application-namespace): Application namespace is an object placed either directly in the global scope or on some other object as a property, holding all code and data making up the application.

The purpose of the application namespace is to

a) have the application form a single logical unit, and

b) avoid collision with 3rd party code such as libraries and frameworks.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace).

so logically it should be name-space of your XML:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

or

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, in my case what my app_name_space space should be?

Comment: try the one given in xmlns:android or xmlns:app in my answer