# Namespaces: how to know how and when to use them? i.e.: xmlns:andorid, xmlns:app, xmlns:tools

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

What is `xmlns:android`, `xmlns:app`, `xmlns:tools` and what's the basic difference between them? and When I should use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `android` & `app` namespaces, use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692768/4409113).

> it is used for all attributes defined in your app, whether by your
>   code or by libraries you import, effectively **making a single global
>   namespace for custom attributes** - i.e., attributes not defined by the
>   android system.
>
> In this case, the appcompat-v7 library uses custom attributes
>   mirroring the `android:` namespace ones to support prior versions of
>   android (for example: `android:showAsAction` **was only added in API11**,
>   but `app:showAsAction` (*being provided as part of your application*)
>   works on all API levels your app does) - obviously using the
>   android:showAsAction wouldn't work on API levels where that attribute
>   is not defined.

About `tools`;

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable **design-time features** (*such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment*) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.

There are also another usages of `tools` namespace which you can see in the strings or etc like:

```
<string name="show_all_apps" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">All</string>
```

Which helps to ignore errors.

Also, there is another which helps to define `TargetedAPI`:

```
tools:targetApi
```

And so much more.

**Read:** https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes